# Showing progress with a RatingBar

Tags: android, android-progressbar, ratingbar

I got this tracker screen that tracks users days of working out and workout sets completed. I would like to add `ProgressBar` or `RatingBar` that displays some sort of progress/rating by increase of my counter.

Lets say that 5 stars or full `ProgressBar` would be when counter2 reaches 300 (counter2 (workout sets completed)).

[image]

My current code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    a = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    a.setDuration(120);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        counter1 = 0;
        counter2 = 0;
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.tracker);

    counter1 = 0;
    counter2 = 0;

    add1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.baddday);
    sub1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsubday);
    add2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.baddset);
    sub2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsubset);
    list = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blist);
    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    display1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayDays);
    display2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplaySets);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/tele.ttf");
    display1.setTypeface(tf);
    display2.setTypeface(tf);

    add1.setOnClickListener(this);
    sub1.setOnClickListener(this);
    add2.setOnClickListener(this);
    sub2.setOnClickListener(this);
    list.setOnClickListener(this);

    SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("countersetting", 0);
    counter1 = setting.getInt("countervalue1", 0);
    counter2 = setting.getInt("countervalue2", 0);
    display1.setText("" + counter1);
    display2.setText("" + counter2);
            bar.setProgress(counter2);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putString("YourTextViewTextIdentifier1", display1
            .getText().toString());
    savedInstanceState.putString("YourTextViewTextIdentifier2", display2
            .getText().toString());
    savedInstanceState.putInt("int", counter1);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("int", counter2);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    display1.setText(savedInstanceState
            .getString("YourTextViewTextIdentifier1"));
    display2.setText(savedInstanceState
            .getString("YourTextViewTextIdentifier2"));
    counter1 = savedInstanceState.getInt("int");
    counter2 = savedInstanceState.getInt("int");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("countersetting", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
    editor.putInt("countervalue1", counter1);
    editor.putInt("countervalue2", counter2);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.baddday:
        counter1 += 1;
        display1.setText("" + counter1);
        add1.startAnimation(a);
        break;
    case R.id.bsubday:
        counter1 -= 1;
        display1.setText("" + counter1);
        sub1.startAnimation(a);
        break;
    case R.id.baddset:
        counter2 += 1;
        display2.setText("" + counter2);
        add2.startAnimation(a);

        bar.setProgress(counter2);
        bar.setMax(300);
        bar.incrementProgressBy(counter2);
        bar.getProgress();



        break;
    case R.id.bsubset:
        counter2 -= 1;
        display2.setText("" + counter2);
        sub2.startAnimation(a);
        bar.setProgress(counter2);
        bar.incrementProgressBy(counter2);
        bar.getProgress();

        break;
    case R.id.blist:
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent i = new Intent(Tracker.this, List.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }, 150);
        list.startAnimation(a);
        break;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: have you looked into the `RatingBar` class? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html or the `ProgressBar` class? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Comment: I did but I need help with some code :(

Comment: go ahead and link to your project (google drive or something) and i can take a look at your code

Comment: anybody else have idea how to achieve this?!

Comment: see my above comment. if you upload your project i can take a look for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lets say that 5 stars or full progressBar would be when counter2
>   reaches 300 (counter2 (workout sets completed))

You already set the correct progress for the `ProgressBar` but you also **increment** the newly set progress again(by the counter value) which will not show the proper results. In the `onCreate` method:

```
bar.setMax(300);
bar.setProgress(counter2); // the initial stored value
```

and in the listeners for the buttons:

```
case R.id.baddset:
    counter2 += 1;
    display2.setText(String.valueOf(counter2));
    add2.startAnimation(a);
    bar.setProgress(counter2);
    break;
case R.id.bsubset:
    counter2 -= 1;
    display2.setText(String.valueOf(counter2));
    sub2.startAnimation(a);
    bar.setProgress(counter2);
    break;
```

Comment: I would alos like to add display text for every +25 counter reach.
So when user starts an app it displays rookie under the progress bar. After reaching +25 in counter2 it displays beginner, after 50 intermediate and so on...
Any idea?

Comment: @lakyberry Add another `TextView` to your layout where you want and in the code for the two buttons above add the following code(after bar.setProgress(counter2)): if (counter2 <= 25) { levelTextView.setText("beginner");} else if (counter2 <= 50) {levelTextView.setText("intermediate");} etc...

Comment: Awsome... :) Thanks Luksprog

Comment: I have a trouble restoring previus state of my levelTextView.
I tried this within onCreate:
levelTextView.setText(String.valueOf(levelTextView));

Comment: I also tried 
levelTextView.setText("levelTextView);
It dosent work. I can't get levelTextView display unitl I press + or - .
When I press it then it displays the current level...

Comment: @lakyberry You have the `conter2` variable in the `onCreate` method so at the end of the `onCreate` method, after you get `counter2` from the preferences simply insert the same logic I told you above, the one with the `if (counter2 < ) etc...`